# How to request a pre-release DevHub?

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, dev-hub, pre-release, sf, org-snapshot

While a pre-release org can be requested for Spring 24 through standard Salesforce signup https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-spring24/, these orgs do not allow to enable the API (to use `sf` cli) and neither to enable it as DevHub.

Is it possible to create a pre-release DevHub-enabled org to try out new Salesforce features such as [org snapshots](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_org_commands_unified.htm#cli_reference_org_create_snapshot_unified)?

Comment: As long as you're not trying to create a package version you should be able to create a preview scratch org associated with your dev hub (we certainly can) where you can do your feature investigations. I don't imagine you could create a new package version from this until preview is finished though.

Comment: @PhilW while is a good idea, is not an option to try commands that require the pre-release feature in the devhub. For example, to try out org snapshot the devhub needs to have it available.

Comment: That's not what I meant; your dev hub should, if you are a partner, be your PBO and that's a production org. You cannot get a preview on that org and would have to wait for it to be upgraded. I'm saying you can create **scratch orgs with preview release** against your dev hub.

Comment: For the org snapshot item, since these require the dev hub to support them that specific feature cannot be tried out until your dev hub is upgraded.

Comment: @PhilW indeed I suspect the same, but when I saw the below blog, I got to think that it's possible to have this special pre-release devhub
https://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2024/01/scratch-org-snapshots-in-spring-24.html?m=1

Comment: The question is... how to get such a pre-release org? I was not aware that there was the option for a permanent pre-release org...

Comment: I think there are a mentions in the blog that they're actually using a Developer Edition org that they've enabled Dev Hub features in rather than a Production org.